Can user modify their own iOS SwiftData/CoreData SQLite data directly with some tools in their devices?
I'm making an iOS app with In-App purchase, thinking about storing user's plan selection in SwiftData.
I wonder if it's possible that an user can modify SwiftData SQLite data directly with some editor tools.
If it's possible, I cannot use SwiftData/CoreData for storing user's plan selection.
Is this possible or not?

With a jailbroken phone, yes. I'm not sure otherwise. This kind of thing is usually stored in your backend server.

Adopt StoreKit 2 and then you don't need to store their purchase data at all. You can fetch their entitlements directly and securely on app launch and simply hold it in memory

I think it is very possible. But if you use SwiftData with iCloud, you could try @Attribute(.allowsCloudEncryption) var .... in your models.
For local SwiftData SQLite, you could encrypt the sensitive properties of your models, so they are stored encrypted
in the SQLite DB, and decrypt them as needed in your App.
Storing the key in keychain, for example.

yes it is very possible for a user to modify the data directly if they have access to the device and the necessary tools to modify the data, they could manipulate the database. using swiftdata is a 'good' choice for ios, but it comes with huge risks.

This is more suitable as a comment than an answer.

@JoakimDanielson But it does answer the question as asked.

@JoakimDanielson it really isn’t. The answer is clear and concise, and provides a suggested alternative. That’s all an answer needs.

I certainly disagree, it talks about necessary tools but does not mention any example so it's very vague and to say it's a "huge risk" to use SwiftData is an exaggeration and not backed up by any evidence or data. So all it says really is "yes it is very possible" and that isn't much of an answer. Then the question is clearly off topic but I guess that isn't relevant to this discussion.

@JoakimDanielson very sorry, im new to stackoverflow so i do not know how to answer questions very clearly. thank you for this, i'll keep in mind to do better.
